# Image processing, 2D convolution

Tags: matlab, image-processing, convolution

I am asked to use conv2 to do the convolution of the red component of an image and a rectangle function but I get an error and I don't know how to handle it.

```
img = imread('test.png');
RED = img(:,:,1);
RECT = ones(10,1) / 10;

J= conv2(double(RED), RECT);

imagesc(J)
```

The error says
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Thanks

Comment: P1 is not defined. Create a [MCVE]

Comment: Based on what little you showed us, I'm guessing you named a variable `imread`, `double`, or `conv2`. Type `clear imread double conv2` and retry your code.

Comment: P1 is RECT, forgot to correct it. Thank you gnovice, in my notebook I named conv2 the calculation of a 1D convolution and I didn't notice..